# Qt (custom build) doesn't use system style on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, user-interface, ubuntu

I have an app I'm developing with Qt 5.4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I had been using the binaries that came with the Qt Creator download, but needed to customize some things, so I built the Qt binaries from source, still version 5.4.2.

Here's the issue I encountered: the gui no longer uses the native style. The left-hand gui is what I want. The right-hand gui is what I get with my custom-build Qt libraries.

[image]

Here's the command I used for the Qt build configuration:

```
./configure -release -nomake examples -no-openssl -no-opengl -no-sql-sqlite -no-openvg -no-icu -no-libjpeg -platform linux-g++ -qt-xcb
```

*Important to note:* The Qt Designer app also has the same non-native gui styling with my custom build, so it's the library's fault and not my app's fault. And since both are using the same version of Qt, I can figure that it's probably an issue with my system or my configuration, and not with Qt itself.

Comment: `qtconfig` is not available for Qt 5.

Comment: Didn't know that. Awesome. According to this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html `You can also set the style for all Qt applications by setting the QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE environment variable.`

Comment: @AaronCampbell, I have a same problem. Did you find solution?

Comment: I haven't touched this project since last year, so I'm sorry but I can't remember.